# How to use rxjs6 partition in typescript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

When I try to use rxjs6 `partition` in typescript a type missmatch error is thrown. Also the example from the official documentation throws that error. I think I have to cast something, but I don't know what. Any suggestions?

```
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs';
import {partition} from 'rxjs/operators';

document.body.innerHTML = "<DIV width=100 height=100></DIV>"


//Example Code from https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/partition
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const parts = clicks.pipe(partition(ev => ev.target.tagName === 'DIV'));
const clicksOnDivs = parts[0];
const clicksElsewhere = parts[1];
clicksOnDivs.subscribe(x => console.log('DIV clicked: ', x));
clicksElsewhere.subscribe(x => console.log('Other clicked: ', x));
```

Error:

> Argument of type 'UnaryFunction, [Observable,
>   Observable]>' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'OperatorFunction'.   Type '[Observable,
>   Observable]' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>       Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '[Observable, Observable]'.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fdqhws

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The typings for `pipe` are currently not flexible enough to support `partition` as a pipeable operator, and the documentation for `partition` isn't very helpful at the time of writing:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2995

I believe that there are calls for it to be made a static function in RxJS7:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3797

As a workaround, try this:

```
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const parts = partition(ev => ev.target.tagName === 'DIV')(clicks);
```